# action of ag-grid cellRenderer element not working

Tags: angular, datatables, event-handling, angular6, ag-grid

I am trying to make my delete button work in my Ag-Grid Table.
But when I am clicking on my delete button the event is not triggering.

Here are my codes :

```
columnDefs = [
  {headerName: 'Language Name', field: 'language_name' },
  {headerName: 'Options', field: 'options', cellRenderer: this.optionsRendererFunc, autoHeight: true, width: 100}
];

deleteBtnClicked(id) {
  console.log(id);
}

optionsRendererFunc(params) {
   return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="deleteBtnClicked(params.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
}
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any error in your console when you click the delete button?

Comment: @Ritesh Nope, not a single clue in console.

Comment: Can you share your updated code?

Comment: @Ritesh I have just changed my `optionsRendererFunc` with your solution,,and in the `//Write your code here` , I have added `this.deleteBtnClicked(params.id)` and that's all.

Comment: can you please change cellRenderer: this.optionsRendererFunc to cellRenderer: this.optionsRendererFunc.bind(this) and see?

Comment: @Ritesh Yes, Now It's working. Thanks. Please update your answer with the edition. I have a question though, I have read in ag-grid documentation somewhere, If you render some element through creating progmatically it causes some performance issue of the grid, If you give this responsibility to ag-grid itself, It parses and create element in it's way which is performance safe. Please let me know If I am wrong. and how ag-grid is rendering the element? and should I do it this way?

Comment: @Ritesh and please can you show how I can handle two buttons for multiple element rendering with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

Define the GridOptions like this,

```
columnDefs: [
        {headerName: 'Language Name', field: 'language_name' },
        {headerName: 'Options'
         template: `<button data-action-type="delete" type="button" >Delete</button>`
        }
    ]
```

And for RowClickEvent Use the below code:

```
     onGridRowClicked(e: any) {
        if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
        let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");
        switch (actionType) {
            case "edit":
                {
                   // code to Edit
                }
            case "delete":
                {
                  // code to Delete
                }
        }
    }
}
```

while clicking the Edit/Delete Button, e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type") in the switch case will redirect to proper code portion.

Comment: This has a simple issue is that, If there is a icon in my button, If I click on Icon nothing happens, but If I click on button then working fine, not to be silly but this really a issue for me.

Comment: That you can write a css class and handle it. I think for the above question this answer works

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. The string you're returning from your function is not compiled with Angular. [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) simply renders that within the grid as a cell renderer.

You can handle it with `rowClicked` event as per below.

```
// 1. Update your grid markup with row click event handler
(rowClicked)="_onRowClicked($event)"


// 2.handle the event in the component

_onRowClicked(e: RowClickedEvent) {
  if (e.event.srcElement !== undefined && e.event.srcElement.getAttribute('class') &&
         e.event.srcElement.getAttribute('class').indexOf('btn-danger') > -1) {

    const id = e.data.id;
    this.deleteBtnClicked(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, in your solution basically the event is triggering when clicking anywhere on the row? then finding out the source element who caused the triggering? If I have another button on the same row, I need to find again the source for that specific button to perform different action? Are you sure this is the clean way to do it?

Comment: Please explain your code unless your solution has no value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
optionsRendererFunc(params) {
    var button= document.createElement('button');
    console.log(params);
    button.innerHTML = 'Del';
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
       // Write your code here
    });
    return button;
}
```

Also update cellRenderer: this.optionsRendererFunc to cellRenderer: this.optionsRendererFunc.bind(this)

Comment: It says > `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteBtnClicked' of undefined`

Comment: I need to make it work with multiple elements such as two buttons, please show a solution on that.